# Error while adding IronPython 2.7 in as interpreter to pydev in eclypse juno windows 8

Tags: python, windows-8, pydev, ironpython

I have iron Python 2.7 installed in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7
```

Iv'e added it to my environment variables as follows

```
path: [...] ;C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\
```

When I try to add it as an interpreter in `pydev` i get the following:

```
"Error getting info on interpreter"
```

And in the error log:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 35; The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
```

When googling solutions i found a suggestion to make sure i have no environment variables 
containing older versions of python (done)
otherwise only solutions for macOS (where this seems to be a common issue)

This problem is not specific to Iron python- the same thing happens when i try the same with python 3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed buy re-installing pydev from a different repository

initially was installed from http://pydev.org/updates repository. reinstalling from this repository did not help- maybe a temporary issue.

reinstalled from http://pydev.org/nightly repository- this did the trick.

Note- the "contact all update sites during install to find required software" was unchecked.